# Remove Multiple Row and If Multiple Row than It Ignore All Row and keep Last Row in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image: Input Image]

I have this type of data. I want this data which `InqNo` is unique and from multiple `InqNo` last row (for `InqNo` 84 it comes only one row from three rows which `Conversationid` is 175). And last output like this.

I want a simple query in SQL.

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
with cte as (
  select [foo], [bar], 
     row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by column3 ) as [rn]
  from table
)
delete cte where [rn] > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use `row_number()` ranking function:

```
;with tblDel as
(
    select  row_number() over (partition by InqNo order by conversionId desc) as rn
            , tbl.*
    from    tbl 
)

delete tblDel
where rn > 1
```

`row_number()` assigns unique ordinal number for each row within partition (partition consists of rows that have same `InqNo`), last row in each partition is always assigned 1 (within partition rows are ordered descending by `converionId`). All rows that are not last in their partition are deleted (rows that have `rn` greater than 1).

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65666/1)